# sql searching a range of var(255) between 3000 and 3500 with out getting 3000558

Tags: sql, search

hello i am using sql with phpmyadmin and i have a database with barcodes i need to search ranges. i am using this code right now but it also picks up anything beyond the number given such as 30005548 or 3500777895. i am trying to only get a list such as 
3000,3001.....3499,3500

SELECT * from " & store & " Where Barcode between '3000' and '3500';

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From the example you have given the data seems numeric and you want numeric semantics so why store as varchar?

Comment: Don't know what kind of SQL you're using but in your WHERE clause use a function to convert to number. Like TO_NUMBER(Barcode) >= 3000 and TO_NUMBER <= 3500

Answer (score 0):

looks like more trial and error has proven a answer that works

"SELECT * from " & store & " Where Barcode between '3000' and '3500' and LENGTH(barcode) = 4"

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the quotes on the numbers.  Like this:
SELECT * from mydatabase WHERE parameter BETWEEN 3000 and 3500;